# Retrieve column names from sqlite3 database with php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have the following piece of code which displays a list of my current table names in my database which works fine.

> ```
> <?php // Display all sqlite tables
>     $db = new SQLite3('data.db');
>     $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");
>
>     while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
>         echo $table['name'] . '<br />';
> } ?>
> ```

Can you display the list of column names for a table like you can do in mysql? I have tried numerous iterations and all have failed.

Just for the record this is the code I used thanks to esqew for the help:

```
<?php // Display all sqlite column names for chosen table
    $db = new SQLite3('data.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info(USERS)");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo $table['name'] . '<br />';
} ?>
```

All tested and working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [SQLite.org - PRAGMA Statements](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info):

```
PRAGMA table_info(sqlite_master);
```

To fit it into your PHP implementation:

```
<?php // Display all sqlite tables
    $db = new SQLite3('data.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info(sqlite_master);");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo $table['name'] . '<br />';
} ?>
```

Comment: Useless, this is table names, not column names.

Comment: @FullDecent OP was asking about column names for the `sqlite_master` table. Would this not be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sqlite table schema parser, I implemented the sqlite table parser for parsing the table definitions in PHP.

https://github.com/maghead/sqlite-parser